# "Cannot access memory at address 0x600b0c" & "No symbol "n" in current context." in case of global & local variable when compiling with gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I searched for solution in Internet and found some results but still getting the error.
I have a local variable n and global variable undefined in my C program.
And Error or bug I got :

```
    print f("Enter value m & n : ");
    (gdb) set variable n = 2
     No symbol "n" in current context.
    (gdb) set variable m = 2
    Cannot access memory at address 0x600b0c
```

Comment: Hard to tell post your Code.

Comment: I tried posting it but I could not do it. There is nothing in my code. I got two variables m global variable and n a local variable uninitialized and written two scanf statements for n & m. thats it. Below u can see my code @S.Iquebal

Comment: there sems to be no problem in your code and gdb is giving no error message in my system.@P Krishnama Naidu

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier to tell if you'd posted some code, but let's suppose that it looks something like this:

```
int m;

int read_nums (void)
{
    printf ("Enter value of m and n: ");
    int n = scanf ("%d");
    m = scanf ("%d");
    return n + m;
}
```

Your GDB instance is sitting on the first line, so `n` is not currently in scope. With an optimising compiler, that is still true if your code looks like this:

```
int m;
int read_nums (void)
{
    int n;
    printf ("Enter value of m and n: ");
    n = scanf ("%d");
    m = scanf ("%d");
    return n + m;
}
```

The compiler transforms the program to minimise the scope of variables quite early in the compilation process.

If you're trying to set the value of n with GDB, it's possible that the variable becomes live after the `scanf` line. In that case, use GDB's `next` command to step until it has been set and then change it with the `set` command (or something like `p n = 2`).

For code as simple as what I wrote, the compiler will completely elide `n` and it will generate something more like this:

```
int m;
int read_nums (void)
{
    printf ("Enter value of m and n: ");
    return scanf ("%d") + (m = scanf ("%d"));
}
```

where `n` never exists. To set that value after the fact, you'll have to allow whatever value is based on `n` to be generated and then set that appropriately instead.

If you can easily recompile your code, you might consider compiling it with `-O0 -g3` (GCC flags, but reasonably standard) to disable all optimisation while you poke around with the debugger: it's often a lot easier to match up with the C code then. Barring bugs in the compiler, you can get everything working with those flags then switch optimisation back on at the end.

I'm afraid I don't know what's going on with the `m` error you see. The address looks rather surprising: maybe you need to tell us more about your environment (linux? embedded?) and post some of your code.

Comment: I am using Kali Linux @ Rupert Swarbrick                               #include<stdio.h>
int m;
function()
{
 printf("\nWelcome to function\n");
}
int main()
{
 int n;
 printf("Enter value m & n : ");
 scanf("%d",&m);
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Local Variable 'n' Value : %d",n); 
 printf("\nGlobal Variable 'm' Value : %d",m);
 printf("\nCalling a function...");
 function();
 return 0;
}

Comment: I've just tried the code you crammed into the comment, compiling with "-g3 -O0" with GCC 5.2.1 and GDB 7.10. Everything works the way I'd expect: I can set and read the values of m, n just fine. To get more help, update your question with a transcript of what you've tried and what you see.